# Error when switching running StartActivity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, stack-trace

I am recently having an error when loading a login activity from my splash screen.  This is resulting in a fatal crash.

Here is the code:

```
 if(response.contains("Success") && isStored == false){
    Intent Login = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, LoginScreen.class);
    Login.putExtra("EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER", phoneNumber);
    startActivity(Login);

    // close this activity
    finish();
    }
```

I noticed that if I switch the LoginScreen.class out with my mainactivity.class, it works fine.  Does anybody have any idea what is crashing here?

Here is the code to LoginScreen:

```
public class LoginScreen extends Activity {
EditText email;
EditText pass;
Button LoginButton;
ImageView image;
String phoneNumber;
String userPhone;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //These 2 lines hide the action bar
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    getActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.emailTxt);
    pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordTxt);

    image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageViewLogo);
    userPhone = getPhoneNumber();

    //Displays the logo in the ImageViewLogo
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.autotrak_logo);

    final String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?$";

    LoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
     @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
           final String userEmail = email.getText().toString();
           final String userPass = pass.getText().toString();

            if(userEmail.length() == 0)
            {
                email.requestFocus();
                email.setError("No Email Entered");
            }
            else if(!userEmail.matches(EMAIL_PATTERN))
            {
                email.requestFocus();
                email.setError("Invalid Email");
            }
           else if(userPass.length() == 0)
            {
                pass.requestFocus();
                pass.setError("No Password Entered");
            }else if(checkForUser(userEmail, userPass).contains("Bad")){
                String toastText = "Incorrect email or password";
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toastText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                pass.requestFocus();
            }else
           {
               SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
               SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
               editor.putString("storedEmail", userEmail);
               editor.putString("storedPass", userPass);
               editor.putString("storedPhone", userPhone);
               editor.apply();

               Intent BluetoothDemo = new Intent(LoginScreen.this, BluetoothDemo.class);
               startActivity(BluetoothDemo);
          }
       }
    });
}

public String checkForUser(String email, String pass) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://xxxx.xxxx.net/xxxx.php");
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pass));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phoneNumber", userPhone));
            try {
                request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream is = entity.getContent();
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(20);

                int current = 0;
                while((current = bis.read()) != -1)
                {
                    baf.append((byte)current);
                }

                String bytesSent = new String(baf.toByteArray());

                // for receiving response from the server
                return bytesSent;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                String stackTrace = Log.getStackTraceString(e);
                String toastText = "Error sending data: " + stackTrace;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toastText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String toastText = "Error preparing data";
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toastText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return null;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public String getPhoneNumber(){
    Bundle extras;
    extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras == null) {
        phoneNumber = null;
    } else {
        phoneNumber = extras.getString("EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER");
    }
    return phoneNumber;

}
```

}

Here is the stacktrace:

```
11-23 13:08:00.626    1242-1242/my.obd2connector E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: my.obd2connector, PID: 1242
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{my.obd2connector/my.obd2connector.LoginScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at my.obd2connector.LoginScreen.onCreate(LoginScreen.java:58)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Would you post your LoginScreen code too?

Comment: Updated to include LoginScreen.

Comment: put your setContentView just below the call to super, just guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

because in `LoginScreen` Activity you are calling `setOnClickListener` method of `LoginButton` before initialization  of `LoginButton` Button instance.so do it as after `setContentView`:

```
LoginButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Login_Button_ID);
```

Comment: Good job sir, It always helps top get another pair of eyes on the code to see these silly mistakes.  Thanks and marked as answer.